# Is there an algorithm to merge this kind of list?

Tags: algorithm, list, merge

I have a list like this:

```
a   a   .   a
b   .   .   a
a   .   a   .
c   .   a   .
```

or in list format

```
[['a', 'a', '.', 'a'],
 ['b', '.', '.', 'a'],
 ['a', '.', 'a', '.'],
 ['c', '.', 'a', '.']]
```

and I want to merge it into `[['a','b','c'],['a'],['a'],['a']]`, or

```
a,b,c    a    a    a
```

so that when two consecutive rows share the same letter at any of the four columns, their elements will be merged non-redundantly. I can do it by pairwise comparisons, but wonder if there are formal algorithms to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: No there isn't special algorithm for this and there isn't special algorithm for calculating 2+2, and you should do your homework yourself.

Comment: @Saeed Actually, there are algorithms for doing this. There aren't algorithms for 2+2, but there are algorithms for both x+x and x+y. I do agree about the homework aspect, though, if it is true.

Comment: @Jingping Let's break this down. First, if it is homework, tag as such. (If it's not, give us the context, it might end up helping a lot.) Second, your description (consecutive rows) does not match your example output. How is there an a in the second entry?

Comment: @glowcoder it is not homework... the original context is a biological question but I was sure introducing the original problem would only confuse things, but basically it is related to merging tandem gene duplications if it makes any sense. There is an 'a' in the second entry of the output because list[0][3]==list[1][3], and so list[0][1] and list[1][1] should be merged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify the language but you can create a [HashMap / HashTable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) for each column and populate it with the column values. (Your key and value will be the same thing.) Populating a HashMap means you cannot have duplicate keys so you will end uo with a list of unique values in each collection. Then pull out the values from each hashMap into an array, or arrays. If the periods in your sample data are actually periods you will have to ignore them as you loop through the array otherwise you will get them as output.

Take a look at [Python dictionaries](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

the pseudo code for this solution (Python will look similar ;-)

- Create a list of dictionaries (list length = # of columns)
- Loop over columns
- Loop over rows
- Insert data into appropriate dictionary
  *
- Loop over list of dictionaries
- Loop over dictionary values
- Create new set of arrays with unique values

Comment: @Sasik I use Python. I don't have too much background in computer science but am learning some algorithms for my work. I feel that the hash map is the right direction for my problem, but I also feel there's quite some gap for me to actually use it. Could you give me some more directions about specific algorithms and how to implement? Thanks.

Comment: In Python you would use dictionaries: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries  See more above.

Comment: I'm not terribly fast with Python so I offered some pseudocode. I'll have more time in a few days. I'll check back to see how you're doing. Until then, try and figure it out. Python is pretty slick for these kinds of algs.

Comment: @ Sasik I might be wrong, but I feel you have many loops in the pseudo code. I'll need this to work for very large data sets and probably need to consider speed issue. Would a graph approach be better?

Comment: From your question I thought this was an exercise so I provided an exercise-like solution. If you really want to do this on large sets of data why not use a database and do it with SQL?

Comment: Thanks Paul Sasik! It's very helpful.